# elgg_get_context() not working

Tags: php, social-networking, elgg

I have been trying to write a plugin on elgg framework. So I tried to call specific css for a particular page by using elgg_extend_view() function which is not working. For example

```
 if(elgg_get_context()){
     elgg_extend_view('css/elgg', 'myplugin/css');
 }/*This works*/
```

But the following doesnt seem to work

```
if(!elgg_get_context()){ //If there is not elggcontext call no_css file
     elgg_extend_view('css/elgg', 'myplugin/no_css');
 }/*This is not working */
```

Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you're misinterpreting expected behavior of `elgg_get_context` function.

Check: http://reference.elgg.org/pageowner_8php.html#a25fe73eb19442b4a4476f18e63abf382 It uses strings as a context name (it has to be pushed first and is expected usually to be set just before pagesetup event)

Conditional extension of `elgg/css` won't work correctly, due to caching. You probably want to use `elgg_register_css` and `elg_load_css` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`elgg_get_context()` returns STRING or NULL

The exclamation (!) is not good in this case.

Try:

```
if(null!==elgg_get_context()){ //If there is not elggcontext call no_css file
    elgg_extend_view('css/elgg', 'myplugin/no_css');
}
```

If any problem try to visualize what the function is returning, see:

`var_dump(elgg_get_context());`

Note: elgg is in version 1.8.18, check if you have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to compare your plugin's context, as elgg will always maintain some context.

so do it like:

```
 if(elgg_get_context() == 'myplugin'){
     elgg_extend_view('css/elgg', 'myplugin/css');
 }
```